# Integrate Instagram feed into Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

Q: How do I allow my users to display their instagram feed on my site?

I have a Rails 5 application that has been relying on an unofficial, and undocumented, API from Instagram (Basically appending /?__1 after the URL). I want to allow all my users to input their profile URL and then display their Instagram feed on their public profiles.

I have look at `https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/` but it says nothing about embedding actual feeds.

What if I let all my users integrate with Instagram using oauth and then query their feed with a specific token?

Would be very interested in hearing what others do. Thanks.